# How do I internally rewrite all requests to subdirectory?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I'm using Laravel 5.6, and I can only upload/edit files to/in the root of the website (`/public_html`). I cannot change the website root to `/public_html/public`. Is it possible to rewrite **all** requests (e.g. `/`, `/login`, `/css/styles.css` etc.) internally to `/public_html/public/`?

I don't know how to write .htaccess files.
I tried many different things I found online. The last thing I tried was this in `/public_html/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: "The last thing I tried was" - and what happened? What was the problem with this code?

Comment: Internal server error.

Comment: The 500 Internal Server Error was probably the result of an internal rewrite loop. You should be able to check this in your server's error log.

Comment: I don't know what happened. I don't have access to the logs at the moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
> ```

You just need an additional *condition* to prevent a rewrite loop. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is empty on the initial request and set to 200 (OK) after the first successful rewrite.

The start/end anchors (`^` and `$`) are not required, since the regex is greedy by default.